# Pandas merge rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a single dataframe like this :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'GameID': 15, 'Column1': 20,'Column2': 25, 'Column3': -15,'Column4': '','Column5': ''}, {'GameID': 15, 'Column1': '','Column2': '','Column3': '','Column4': 30,'Column5': 40}])
```

The output is like this :

```
   GameID Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
0      15      20      25     -15
1      15                              30      40
```

What I'm tring to do here is to merge my row, meaning that the output will be like

```
   GameID Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
0      15      20      25     -15      30      40
```

I've tried to groupby but the result isn't the one expected

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1.groupby('GameID'))
    0                                                  1
0  15     GameID Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Colu...
```

Any suggestion on this topic will be much appreciated

Thanks

Geoffrey

Comment: `df1.groupby('GameID').first()`.

Comment: `df1.mask(df1=='').groupby('GameID',as_index=False).first()
`

Comment: Thank you, trying both options here, second one is working
I only had to add

`df.fillna('')`
`df.reset_index(inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

This is another alternative without `groupby()` as greatly suggested in the comments, using `np.nan` and `fillna()`:

```
df1 = df1.replace({'':np.nan}).fillna(method='bfill').head(1)
```

Output:

```
GameID  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
0   15  20.0    25.0    -15.0   30.0    40.0
```

Comment: thank you. The sample I've posted is just a sample. I can have multiples lines with empty values to merge, so not sure the head(1) will work here ? Also, my df is approx 10K lines

Comment: `.head(1)` will guarantee you get returned your first row. You can also use `.loc[0,:]` for the same matter. Do you want to return more rows than the first one?